# I need clarification for State and Lifecycle of react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently learning React and I don't fully understand why this is wrong:

```
// Wrong
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment,
});
```

And this is correct:

```
// Correct
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
}));
```

Could someone give me a real world example where i can use this "second form of `setState()`" that accepts a function?

This is the [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a `CheckBoxComponent`, whose state you initialize like this in the constructor:

`this.state = {enabled: true}`

You want to update its state when a user clicks on the checkbox. So you write this click handler:

```
function toggleCheckbox() {
    this.setState({enabled: ???});
}
```

This kind of situation is what the second type of setState is for. The click handler should be written as:

```
function toggleCheckbox() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({enabled: !prevState.enabled}));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you
>   should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

1) You can just use this snippet in **most situations** as long as you didn't use the current state/props to calculate for the next state.

For example, this snippet only goes to fetch data from github and update to its state. We can just put an object inside this.setState().

```
class FetchGithub extends react.Component{
  state = {
    //...
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/commits')
      .then(data => this.setState(data.json()))
      .catch(err => this.setState(err));
  }
}
```

2) But once the scenario is to use the current state/props to calculate for the next state, then you need to put instead a function to make sure that our current state gets updated already.

```
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
}));
```

**[Updated]**

Since props is the argument that is been passed from this component's parent or redux's reducers, which means it takes time to process. So you also need to make sure the props is the most updated one.

Let's look at your code example again. There should be 2 components:

1. Parent component, that control either +1 or -1 -> AdjustComponent
2. Child component, just for display the result -> DisplayComponent

So the proper flow is the user click on +1/-1, AdjustComponent passes the **props** into DisplayComponent. And then DisplayComponent get to update its state by its current state and props sent by AdjustComponent. And show to the screen.

But what if the user click on -1 and then +1 very very very quickly or if user's computer suddenly has huge loading to deal with that affect their browser performance. So that when you use this snippet:

```
this.setState({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
});
```

The newest props(which should be +1) hasn't been received from AdjustComponent yet, but DisplayComponent updated already, using the old props.increment, which is -1 that leads to the wrong result.

Comment: it is you who down vote? I would be curious why, and you should at least correct your answer: 
.then(data => this.setState({data: data.json()}))

Comment: how about the second parameter props in function? what is that for? could you give another example for second parameter "props"?